# What figure of speech is the following statement?

Tags: figures-of-speech

What figure of speech is the following statement?

**"If you scratch my back, I'll scratch yours"**

A friend said that to me today.

Comment: I'd say it's just a [**metaphor**](http://websters.yourdictionary.com/metaphor) *- a figure of speech containing an implied comparison, in which a word or phrase ordinarily and primarily used of one thing is applied to another*. But note that although the underlying reference is to ***apes/chimps/etc.*** engaging in "mutual grooming" to the benefit of each, the metaphor only really invokes that (socially) beneficial activity, not the simian nature of the normal *literal* participants.

Comment: You understand that if you help me in my area of need, then I will repay you in your need, which may be a different area?

Comment: What do you mean by "what"? That is, what are you asking about - the type of figure (see FF's comment), the meaning of the idiom (see YB's comment), or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around:  Wiktionary calls it a "proverb," which isn't much help.

I view this as an idiom, and a [published book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ijulh9-sb-YC&pg=PT187&lpg=PT187&dq=%22you%20scratch%20my%20back,%20I%27ll%20scratch%20yours%22%20%20metaphor%20or%20idiom&source=bl&ots=3rzlaUVAeE&sig=ua5W1jz-unBgrpbnFEkwBy-cEzc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipwt_k18zUAhVE1oMKHWiJChMQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%22you%20scratch%20my%20back%2C%20I'll%20scratch%20yours%22%20%20metaphor%20or%20idiom&f=false)  agrees with me. Quote:

[image]